# How to move bezier curve in 3D space?

Tags: modeling

I want to move a bezier curve around an object (it could be a tentacle). I am finding it impossible to position the bezier curve accurately. Is there a universal way that could make this process a breeze?

Comment: Hello could you please show some screenshots? In what way is it impossible?

Comment: @moonboots well i am wrapping an octopus tentacle around an organic object. I have been constantly switching between top-front-left-back view and adjusting the handle so very slightly. That's just not the way i know. So is there a better way?

Comment: Is it supposed to be animated? You could use a Shrinkwrap modifier on your curve to make it stick to the object, or maybe a snap to faces? Another way would be to duplicate your object, cut an edge with a knife, only keep this edge and convert to curve? An image of your scene may help...

Comment: @moonboots That may help. I will try out and let you know. Also I found another way, using Draw freehand Spline (On Surface). Only issue is I don't know how to continue the curve once I release the left mouse button